# Regarding decimal -> hexadecimal conversion without using pre-existing utils or methods

Tags: java, hex

I am currently working on assignments related to Class (JAVA),

and I am near to the finishing line but my public string getHex() will be just returning me value of 0.

To make it easier to view, I have uploaded the codes I've been working on:

https://codeshare.io/5DAzYk

So the upper half is the TestSmallInt.java program that runs based on SmallInt.java class file.

I can't figure out why the getHex() wouldn't work !

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Do not post links to code. Copy/paste the *relevant* parts into the question.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry ! and thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 1):

The actual logic in your getHex method is fine, but it doesn't work because your other methods (and the getHex method) mutate 'value', so by the time you call getHex() the value has been destroyed.

Adjust your code such that if you need to mutate the value then you make a copy of it, eg:

```
public String getHex() {
    int number = value;
    // now mutate number, not value
```

Incidentally, declaring `value` final would flag this mutation up automatically:

```
private final int value;

public SmallInt(final int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
...
```

Thus, the edited code would be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestSmallInt
{
    /** Main method */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a desired number: ");
        int decimal = sc.nextInt();
        SmallInt number = new SmallInt (decimal);

        String numberAsString = number.getDec ();
        String numberAsBin = number.getBin ();
        String numberAsHex = number.getHex ();
        System.out.println ("Your number in decimal is " + numberAsString);
        System.out.println ("Your number in binary is " + numberAsBin);
        System.out.println ("Your number in hexadecimal is " + numberAsHex);
        sc.close();
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class SmallInt
{
    private final int value;

    public SmallInt (int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getDec ()
    {
        return ""+ value;
    }

    public String getBin (){
        int number = value;
        if (number == 0) {
                 return "0";
         }
         String binary = "";
         while (number > 0) {
                 int rem = number % 2;
                 binary = rem + binary;
                 number = number / 2;
         }
         return binary;
    }

    public String getHex (){
        String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        int number = value;
         if (number <= 0) {
                 return "0";
                }
         int base = 16;   // flexible to change in any base under 16
         String hex = "";
         while (number > 0) {
             int digit = number % base;              // rightmost digit
             hex = digits.charAt(digit) + hex;  // string concatenation
             number = number / base;
         }
         return hex;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried implementing your method.  So I tried the int number = value; but this still end up bringing me hexadecimal = 0 .

Comment: Did you update all methods? getBin also mutates value etc

Comment: So do I add  int number = value; to both getBin and getHex ?  Also, declaring value gives lot of compiling error saying I can't declare it

Comment: Thanks , I did it as your way of creating copy of value as index, and altering both getBin and getHex allowed me to calculate both and display both results. Thanks so much, you've been great help !

Comment: I have updated your example appropriately (removing the setDec method - it's not needed if you set the value in the constructor). The out-of-range check arguably belongs in the code where you capture the value from the scanner - you can then loop until you get an acceptable value